# Find the sum of the infinite Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Problem**

> Let $F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1,$ and $F_n = F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$. Find the value of the infinite sum $$\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{2}{27}+\cdots+\dfrac{F_n}{3^n}+\cdots.$$

This sort of looks like an arithmetico-geometric series but except for the fact that the fiboncci sequence is not arithmetic. I couldn't think of a way to continue.

Comment: Hint:  The generating function for the Fibonacci numbers is $\sum F_nx^n=\frac 1{1-(x+x^2)}$.

Comment: Do you know the generating function for the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: Does that generating function work for infinite sums only?

Comment: Hint: what is the closed formula of Fn?

Comment: That is known as Binet's formula.

Comment: @Puzzled417  there's a version for finite sums.  Let $f_n(x)$ be the terms of the generating function up to $x^n$, then look at $f_n(x)-xf_n(x)-x^2f_n(x)$ and use the recursion.  Most terms go away, and you can just gather up the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Let $s_n=F_n/3^n$, we have: 
$$
s_n={1\over3}s_{n-1}+{1\over9}s_{n-2},
$$
that is:

$$
\sum_{k=3}^\infty s_n={1\over3}\sum_{k=2}^\infty s_{n}+{1\over9}\sum_{k=1}^\infty s_{n}.
$$
If $S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty s_{n}$ is finite (which is true, because $s_n<(2/3)^n$), it follows that:
$$
S-{1\over3}-{1\over9}={1\over3}\left(S-{1\over3}\right)+{1\over9}S,
$$
whence $S=3/5$.

Comment: I don't understand you last line.

Comment: $\sum_{k=3}^\infty s_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty s_n-s_1-s_2=S-1/3-1/9$ and $\sum_{k=2}^\infty s_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty s_n-s_1=S-1/3$.

Comment: What about $s_0$? You seem to be shifting the index of the series around.

Comment: But your sum starts with $s_1$! And anyway $s_0=0$.

Comment: Sorry. You are right.

Comment: Why did you computation in the last step only work if it were finite?

Comment: Let $F=\sum_{k=1}^\infty F_n$. Then by the same argument you would find $F=-1$. In short: you cannot do arithmetic with infinite quantities.

Comment: How would you set up the recursion in that case? Just by using the Fibonacci recursion?

Comment: Yes: $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$, and taking the sum from $3$ to $\infty$ one gets $F-1-1=F-1+F$.